# How does one prove:$\nabla(\vec{\mu_m}\cdot\vec{B})\cdot\vec{dr}=0$?

Tags: electromagnetism

Work done by a magnetic force(even over an infinitesimally short displacement)=0

*Net Force* on a current loop in an external magnetic field is given by: $$\vec{F}=\nabla(\vec{\mu_m } \cdot \vec{B})$$

How does one prove: $$dW=\nabla(\vec{\mu_m} \cdot \vec{B})\cdot\vec{dr}=0$$

$\vec{\mu_m}$: Magnetic Moment of the current loop.

Comment: Magnetic force cannot perform work but electric field can do work.Such a field may result from the spatial variation of B from the curl B equation[comment to the answer may be considered]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago. It is clear that an electromagnet does produce work, to solve the paradox you need to take into account the generator that runs the current and balance the energy ( Griffiths p211, introduction to electrodynamics).
In other words, if the magnetic moment is created by a current, the system does produce a net work, but deeper analysis shows that it is not created by the magnetic force (qvxB)  but by the generator.

Comment: You can think of redistribution of charges and currents elsewhere(gadgets producing the field) to produce an electric field due to variations of magnetic field   at some fixed point. But a pure magnetic field which does not vary with time cannot perform any work.What would be your mechanism for accounting for such variations of $\vec{B}$ in evaluating:$ \nabla (\vec{\mu_m}.\vec{B}).\vec{dr}$. What would be the mechanism of including electric field in the said evaluation of elementary work?

Comment: I have never had a clear answer, but the most probable explanation for a permanent magnet lifting a weight is a magnetic domain reconfiguration. In other word, the magnet looses some of its force each time you use it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why there is an electric force if V and B are parallel (VxB=0). However, the magnetic field created by a magnet is non uniform so indeed  electrons, in the stell ball lifted up, experience an electric field. There is an other source of energy: the ball is occupying a volume of space which is filled with magnetic energy. If the ball changes of location, the energy stored in the magnetic field changes. 
However, if one takes all these possible source of energy for a permanent magnet one has also to do it for an  electric coil and Griffith's solution is wrong.

Comment: Let the magnetic field be in the x direction.If the observer moves along the y direction with a uniform speed v,we have $\vec{E}=\gamma(\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$. The electric field accelerates the charged changing its speed and doing work. Initially there was a  acceleration normal to the direction of motion. But now we have acceleration due to change of speed also . If the net acceleration changes the radiating power should be different from the two frames.But energy is not an invariant wrt frame transformation though it is a conserved quantity. It might have different values in differentframes

Comment: Spatial variation of $\vec{B}$ can produce an electric field:$\nabla \times \vec{B}=\mu_0 \vec{j}+\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$.If $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{dr}=\nabla(\vec{\mu_m}\cdot\vec{B})\cdot\vec{dr}$ to produce non-zero work then,$\vec{E}=\nabla(\vec{\mu_m}\cdot\vec{B})$. How do you prove that by direct calculation?[here you have a view of the problem through the differential equations which are supposed to represent the physical conditions accurately.]

Comment: Edit:For the above comment $\int \vec{E}\rho dV=\nabla(\vec{\mu_0}\cdot\vec{B})\cdot\vec{dr}$Integration should cover all the chage in the current loop.

Comment: Point to Observe:If $\vec{B}$ varies spatially only in the z direction,we may have electric forces only in the y-z plane and not in the z direction.(Initial electric field is assumed to be zero).This follows from the Curl  B equation The model proposed will not produce any force in the z-direction initially.Magnetic force being normal to $\vec{B}$ will also be on the x-y plane. There will no force in the z direction --electrical or magnetic in nature.

Comment: $B_x$ and $B_y$ have been assumed to be zero individually in the above comment.Small non-zero values of $B_x$ and $B_y$ definitely changes the picture. What about B_z?It as not supposed to produce any acceleration in the z-direction directly through magnetic effects or indirectly through electrical forces!

Comment: I just skimmed these comments, but I do not know why we're not done here: You've written the *net* force, and the work done by it is nonzero because we're not just considering the magnetic field but also the magnetic moment (which is supplied by some generator).

Comment: @Chris Gerig , I think the initial problem has somewhat drifted to : where is taken from the energy when a permanent magnet does some work (like lifting a weight). For an electromagnet Griffith's solution shows it comes from the generator (and not the field). For a permanent magnet, I can only think about magnetic domain reconfiguration, but it is pure speculation and a paper/ref would be welcome.

Comment: Ah I think I see: We can assume we have a fixed current already flowing through some closed wire, producing a fixed magnetic moment. Then for a permanent magnet providing an external force and moving the wire/moment, it must have done work. So yes, here there can be re-orienting of the spins that decrease the magnitude of the resultant B-field. This is what must happen, because energy isn't coming from some external power source.

Comment: You can even forget the current that produces the magnetic moment. A steel ball can be lifted by a permanent magnet.